# BULK INSERT tab-delimited file - With commas in Description

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file With the BULK INSERT Function. I am doing it through SQL because it can be an automated process. The problem I picked up is that the CSV file I get from the client has commas in the Item Description i.e Rosetta 10,5x25x4 - When I try to import it that comma in the description causes a problem: Here is the Script I am running:

```
BULK INSERT ORDERS_DATA
FROM 'C:\back_orders_2013.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',  
    TABLOCK
)
```

Is there a way to ignore that like in excel where you treat consecutive delimiters as one?

Comment: If it's tab delimited, why is your field terminator comma?

Comment: It is not tab delimited - it is comma delimited but in some of the descriptions there's also a comma. I am trying to ignore the comma in those fields. This is the full description in the DESCRIPTION Column - Rosetta 10,5x25x4

Comment: If the DESCRIPTION column has comma, then there should be text qualifier  that is used to differentiate your field data from your delimiter.

Comment: Where would I add the text qualifier? Just read up on it and it looks like I need to create another .txt file that specifies each column data. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.. You can find the example of sample csv in the  link:http://www.msbiguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/1.jpg

Comment: I have managed to read the data correctly but I keep getting an error: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="18" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="19" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\n' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
     </RECORD>
     <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="RKID" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
      <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="ORNO" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
      <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="PONO" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
      <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="ITEM_CODE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="ITEM_DESCRIPTION" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="ORDER_QTY" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="DELIVER_QTY" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="B_QTY" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="RTS_DATE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="PRICE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="PLEV" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="DISCOUNT1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="DISCOUNT2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="DISCOUNT3" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="TOTAL" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="CURRENCY" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="17" NAME="ORDER_DATE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="18" NAME="BKYN" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="19" NAME="PENTA_REF" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
     </ROW>
    </BCPFORMAT>
```

This works 100% and the error I received:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated

Was because of the length of one of my data fields.

Comment: Sorry I see it's still not bringing the Description in right. I notice that the descriptions that has a comma is inserted into " ".That is field 5. How should I change That?